# Inscribed angle theorem for hyperbola - is this result well known?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, conic-sections, special-relativity

I (re-)discovered the following result recently.

### Inscribed angle theorem for hyperbola

The Minkowski inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}$, $u\cdot v=u_1v_1-u_2v_2$, satisfies a version of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $(u \cdot v)^2 \geq u^2 v^2$.  If $u$ and $v$ are spacelike vectors (i.e. $u^2 >0$ and $v^2>0$) then it is possible to define an 'angle' between them via $\cosh(\theta)=\frac{u \cdot v}{|u||v|}$.  In the language of special relativity, $\theta$ is the rapidity between two observers moving along tangent vectors $u$ and $v$.

The analogue of the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}$ is the hyperbola $y^2-x^2=1$.  Take 3 points on the upper branch of the hyperbola $P_0=(\sinh(\theta_0),\cosh(\theta_0))$ and $P_1$ and $P_2$ defined similarly.

The gradient of $P_1P_0$ is

$\frac{\cosh(\theta_0)-\cosh(\theta_1)}{\sinh(\theta_0)-\sinh(\theta_1)}=\frac{2\sinh\left(\frac{\theta_0+\theta_1}{2}\right)\sinh\left(\frac{\theta_0-\theta_1}{2}\right)}{2\cosh\left(\frac{\theta_0+\theta_1}{2}\right)\sinh\left(\frac{\theta_0-\theta_1}{2}\right)}=\tanh\left(\frac{1}{2}(\theta_0+\theta_1)\right)$.

So the angle between $P_1P_0$ and $P_2P_0$ is given by

$\cosh(\theta)=\frac{\left( \matrix{1\\\tanh\left(\frac{\theta_0+\theta_1}{2}\right)} \right)\cdot\left( \matrix{1\\\tanh\left(\frac{\theta_0+\theta_2}{2}\right)} \right)}{\sqrt{1-\tanh^2\left(\frac{\theta_0+\theta_1}{2}\right)} \sqrt{1-\tanh^2\left(\frac{\theta_0+\theta_2}{2}\right)}}=\cosh\left(\frac{\theta_0+\theta_1}{2}\right)\cosh\left(\frac{\theta_0+\theta_2}{2}\right)-\sinh\left(\frac{\theta_0+\theta_1}{2}\right)\sinh\left(\frac{\theta_0+\theta_2}{2}\right)=\cosh\left(\frac{1}{2}(\theta_1-\theta_2)\right)$.

So $\theta=\frac{1}{2}(\theta_1-\theta_2)$ is independent of $P_0$.

### Relation to circular inscribed theorem

This proof is very similar to a proof of the Euclidean [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) for a circle - the hyperbolic trig identity can be replaced by an ordinary trig identity.

### Question

Is this result well-known?  Wikipedia mentions a [similar result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Inscribed_angles_for_hyperbolas_y_=_a/(x_%E2%88%92_b)_+_c_and_the_3-point-form) for hyperbolae of the form $y=\frac{1}{x}$, but there the 'angle' measure (ratio of gradients of lines) is not obviously related to the Minkowski metric, nor obviously generalisable to other rectangular hyperbolae.

**Nonetheless, it seems like this is a result which should be known already.  If so, does anybody have a reference?**

Comment: Yes, I thought along these lines too.  There is a natural analogue of the theorem that the angle at the centre of a circle is twice the angle at the circumference: the lines $P_1O$ and $P_2O$ indeed meet at 'angle' $\theta_1-\theta_2$, which is twice the angle between $P_1P_0$ and $P_2P_0$.

Comment: This is not hard to see: $P_1O$ and $P_2O$ have tangents $(\sinh\theta_1,\cosh\theta_1)$ and $(\sinh\theta_2,\cosh\theta_2)$.  So the inner product leads to a subtraction formula for $\cosh$.

Comment: There is in fact also an analogue of Thales' theorem.  A 'diameter' of the hyperbola is a line passing through the origin, i.e. connecting $P_1$ to $P_1'=-P_1$.  The gradient of $P_1'P_0$ is $\coth\left(\frac{\theta_0+\theta_1}{2}\right)$.  So the inner product of the tangents to $P_1P_0$ and $P_1'P_0$ is $1-\tanh\left(\frac{\theta_0+\theta_1}{2}\right)\coth\left(\frac{\theta_0+\theta_1}{2}\right)=0$.  Hence, although the 'angle' construction fails because $P_1'P_0$ is timelike, these lines are orthogonal in the Minkowski metric.